# SQL Server 2012 Basic way of removing doubles?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and this is just related with school.

I'm restricted to the commands `SELECT`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`

I have this code

```
Use Northwind

SELECT DISTINCT
    ProductID, UnitPrice, Discount
FROM 
    [Order Details]
WHERE
    Unitprice > 100 AND Discount != 0
```

By using `distinct`, there should be no doubles, however I still somehow manage to get this?

Edit : The assignment is to have unique productID, so it's basically gonna end up with 29 and 38 only. Total 2 rows according to the assignment :S

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x45Vf.png

[image]

Comment: If you want to show a short demo, you can use SQLFiddle.com to set up your table and queries. I find it to better than linking to images in general.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? There's no dupes. The result set shows different combinations of productid, price and discount.

Comment: Your question says you want to remove duplicates. How do you want your result to look like?

Comment: Select distinct is going to return distinct combinations of records

Comment: The assignment is to have unique productID, so it's basically gonna end up with 29 and 38 only, only 2 rows

Comment: You can see the difference by selecting less columns.  If you select just distinct ProductID you will get back 2 records, 29 and 38.

Comment: @SchmitzIT: yeah - of course - I needed to clean my glasses :-)

Comment: @MertDemirsü - Then see the answer by John Wesley Gordon. You're getting "dupes" because the combination of the fields was different. If you just need distinct productids, simply don't use the other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will allow you to just get the ProductID that are unique

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ProductID
FROM 
[Order Details]
WHERE
Unitprice > 100 AND Discount != 0
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think it'd be that easy, it was just me being overall stupid. The assignment had a total of 1column and was just a continuation of the assignment i did before which could be solved with 3 columns to be more "clear", i basically did hit a dead end i assume xD